# Which columns should I be indexing?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that takes an insanely long time to execute. Here's the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `posts`.`id` IN (... MANY MANY DOZENS OF IDs ...)
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC;
```

Would I create an index on just `id` or on both `id` and `created_at`?

Comment: You can create an index on both but your fundamental approach is flawed. You should instead insert those IDs into a table and join to it.

Answer (score 1):

For your query, an index only on `posts(id)` is best.  If you had only one `id` in the list, then you could do `posts(id, creaated_at)`.

If the `order by` is taking most of the time, you could try this version:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*
      from posts p
      order by created_at desc
     ) p
where p.id in (. . .);
```

Under some circumstances, this might prevent the sort if you have an index on `posts(created_at)`.  I'm not thrilled with this formulation because it depends on the subquery returning ordered results -- something that works in practice in MySQL.

Comment: If there was only one ID, why would you need to reorder?

Comment: @FrankerZ . . . If the `id` is unique, there would be no need to re-order.